# Using callback to print json data

Tags: javascript, json, callback

Trying to get my json data from a php file and display.

So far I was able to request the data with ajax and log the data it to the console. (At least one thing seems to be working).

Then I attempted to use a callback so my script will wait for the data before it executes the display function. I followed a tutorial for this step by step but I must be doing something wrong because in the inspector it throws an error that my `jsonData` is not defined.

Then I try to display the data but without the callback working properly it won't work.

I'm going to try and explain what I did:

1.
I wait for the document to load before running my script

```
$(document).ready(scriptWrapper);
```

2.
I wrap the whole thing up in with a single function

```
function scriptWrapper(){
  displayJson();
}
```

3.
I start the function with my callback parameter

```
function requestJson(_callback){
```

4.
Request my data from my php file using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/test/senate.php",
    success: result,
});
```

5.
Send the result of the data to the console.log

```
function result(jsonData){
    console.log (jsonData);
}
```

6.
This marks the end of the callback

```
_callback();
```

7.
Start the displayJson function

```
function displayJson(){
```

8.
execute `requestJson()` with the `showData()` function as the parameter which I think means `showData` will wait for the callback before executing.

```
requestJson(showData());
```

9.
This is the function that will display the json data in my output div.

```
function showData(){
    $(".output").append(jsonData);
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

I have a live version here [congress.digitango.com/test/results.php](http://congress.digitango.com/test/results.php)

The full code is:

```
<div class="output"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function scriptWrapper(){
  displayJson();
}

function requestJson(_callback){ 
  $.ajax({
    url: "/test/senate.php",
    success: result,
  });

  function result(jsonData){
    console.log (jsonData);
  }
  _callback();
}

function displayJson(){
  requestJson(showData());
  function showData(){
    $(".output").append(jsonData);
  }
}
$(document).ready(scriptWrapper);  
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entire code is boilerplate. Empty functions that do nothing but call other functions and each other and callbacks... It's confusing and pointless. You are over-engineering. Don't do that.

You can condense everything you wrote into 3 lines.

```
<div class="output"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $.getJSON("/test/senate.php").done(function (data) {
    $(".output").append(data);
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function that you specify as `success` *is* the callback function. It will be called with the result of the request:

```
function requestJson () { 
  $.ajax({
    url: "/test/senate.php",
    success: result // call the 'result' function when you're done
  });

  function result (jsonData) {
    // do something with the data
  }
}
```

You could then do something like this:

```
function requestJson (callback) { // we accept the callback function as the parameter
  $.ajax({
    url: "/test/senate.php",
    success: callback, // call the callback function when you're done
  });
}

function displayJson () {
  requestJson(showData); // use 'showData' as the callback function

  function showData (jsonData) {
    $(".output").append(jsonData);
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do this to fix and simplify the code

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

function scriptWrapper(){
  requestJson();
}

function requestJson(){ 

  $.ajax({
    url: "/test/senate.php",
    success: displayJson,
  });

}

function displayJson(jsonData){

  $(".output").append(jsonData);

}

$(document).ready(scriptWrapper);  

</script>
```

I'm not able to run the code at the moment but you may also need to change   $(".output").append(jsonData); to   $(".output").first().append(jsonData);

[JQuery's $.ajax documentation has some helpful example of how to use callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)